# Is the window object new in HTML5?

Tags: html, dom, web

Before HTML5 did the window object exist? If its not, is the performance attribute new? I tried googling for it but can't find anything other than a specification document saying it has been defined, that doesn't mean its new necessarily.

Comment: The `window` object is just the global object in the browser environment. It's been like this ever since...

Comment: window object is not new in HTML5. Actually its not related to HTML, its JavaScript.

Comment: @kiranvj — HTML 5 defines a lot of DOM APIs, it blurs the line a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Before HTML5 did the window object exist?

Yes. `window` has been the default object for as long as there has been JS in a browser environment.

> If its not, is the performance attribute new?

It comes from the [Navigation Timing](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/) specification.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for the link, that's exactly what i've been looking for the past hour